# Studying topology on $\mathbb{Q}$ with an example

Tags: general-topology

I am studying mathematics on my own and today I am learning topology of rationals.

I want to analyze the topology through some examples.

Let $X=\mathbb{Q}$ be the set of rational numbers and let $d$ be standard Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{Q}$

A very important result:
[Restrict a metric, gives same topology as subspace topology from larger space X](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528230/restrict-a-metric-gives-same-topology-as-subspace-topology-from-larger-space-x)

Example 1: $A=\{r\in\mathbb{Q}: r^2<2\}$

***Is $A$ closed?***

A is closed in $\mathbb{Q}$ as $A=\mathbb{Q}\cap [-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$

***Is $A$ open?***

$A$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$ as $A=\mathbb{Q}\cap(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$

***Is $A$ compact and connected?***

I am stuck here. I know the definitions but I am not able to proceed.

Comment: What are your definitions of compact and connected?

Comment: We say a topological space $X$ is connected if if it can be written as the disjoint union of two non empty open sets.  A topological space $X$ is connected if for every open cover of $X$ there is a finite sub cover. @Arthur

Comment: I think your definition of "connected" is turned around. That's the definition of a disconnected space.

Comment: @Arthur Sorry for the error. You are right.

Comment: Q is totally disconnected: only the singeltons are connected subsets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting $A_s=\{r\in\mathbb Q\mid r^2<s\}=\mathbb Q\cap(-\sqrt s,\sqrt s)$ it is evident that the sets $A_s$ are open for $0<s<2$ and cover $A$.

Can you find a finite subcover?

---

We have $A=\{r\in\mathbb Q\mid r^2<\frac{1}{2}\}\cup \{r\in\mathbb Q\mid \frac{1}{2}<r^2<2\}$ since $\{r\in\mathbb Q\mid r^2=\frac12\}=\varnothing$.

The sets are open, not empty and disjoint.

Answer (score 2):

Not compact. Consider the open cover
{ $\mathbb{Q}\cap(-\sqrt{2},r)$:  r in A }

Not connected.  Let r be an irrational in $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ and consider 
$(-\sqrt{2},r), (r,\sqrt{2})$ both intersected by Q.